# How do you link a portion of code to a Test Case with MS Test Manager or TFService 2013?

Tags: debugging, testing, visual-studio-2012, tfs, testcase

I am currently using Team Foundation Service 2013. I'm going to give you an example and I want to know if it's possible:

1. I create an application.

   if (testPassed){ Console.WriteLine("The program"); }
2. I want to select the code and create a test case knowing that my pass test case is related to this portion of code.
3. Test Case:
   Step: Run the program
   Expected: The program should output "The program passed!"
4. The Tester runs the test case and fails it because the output was "The program"
5. The bug shows up in "My Work" in the "Team Explorer" tab (Which it already does)
6. I select the test case and it automatically highlights the same code I highlighted as being related to the test case I created.

For anyone that has experience with TFService 2013 or Test Manager, how do I link code in Visual Studio 2013 to a Unit Test? This would be HUUUGE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can track code coverage in Microsoft Test Manager when the testers manually execute test cases.  I wrote a article on this last year.  It isn't exactly what you are asking for but I think it gets close.  I haven't tried it in TFService so I'm not 100% sure it will work there.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/11/28/code-coverage-in-microsoft-test-manager-in-visual-studio-update-1.aspx

Mike

Comment: Thanks Mike, I think I can make this work. I didn't think about linking a manual test case to my unit tests. This should get me the result I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to link your `coding test` with id of `workitem` created in `Microsoft Test Manager.`

1. Create test case in Microsoft Test manager
2. Create test project in visual studio
3. Create test typed "Coded UI Tests"
4. Windows appears , select link to id Workitem (Select find button, and edit your query WIQL or enter directly id)